# Avoid repeating the selector inside a jQuery callback

Tags: jquery

I was working on a small script and I noticed something that had a repeating element. In this case `$('#theSelect1 ..')` is repeated and I would like to avoid it.

```
$('#theSelect1').change(function(){
        //console.log ($(this));
        console.log(  
        $("#theSelect1 option:selected").text() // is there a way to change #theSelect1 to be $(this) inside this statement?  I try not to repeat things.  
        );
})
```

This is the HTML

```
            <select id="theSelect1">
            <option value="foo" selected="selected">1</option>
            <option value="bar">2</option>
            <option value="foobar">3</option>
```

Thank you

Comment: Short answer - yes. replace $("#theSelect1 option:selected").text() with $(this).find('option:selected").text()

Comment: Whoa fast reply! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$(this).children("option:selected").text();
```

This will look through the child elements of the current elements for which match your selector. This only looks at the first level descendants, so use the following if you want any descendants:

```
$(this).find("option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
var selectOne = $('#theSelect1').change(function(){
                     selectOne.find('option:selected').text(); 
                 });
```

Comment: why would you do this over using $(this) out of interest?

Comment: You cache the object in the `selectOne` variable. This way if you need it again you don't have to query the `DOM`.

Comment: $(this) does not query the DOM again either.

Comment: It has to remake the jQuery object.

Comment: That is a good point, I'd be interested to see a performance test.

Comment: It's just another example of doing `var $this = $(this)` inside a callback where you'll use the object a lot.